# How to change/add characteristics on HM-10?

Tags: bluetooth

I have been reading about the UUID on the HM-10 and multiple sources say that "The main part of the user UUID service (FFE0) and the main part of the custom characteristic can be changed using the AT commands. You can also add another characteristic." but I can't find any information or AT commands for this.

Comment: Would you mind sharing a bit of context? What you're doing? What your Bluetooth setup is? What you already tried and so forth? Please add those things via [edit] to your question to help people understand better and make good answers more likely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [AT commands list for the HM-10](http://www.martyncurrey.com/?wpdmdl=5917) you’ll find commands `AT+UUID` which allows changing the service UUID and `AT+FFE2` which enables control of the second service/characteristic.

Note that features may depend on the firmware version on your module, and that it’s definitely not very flexible.